# getting 502 errors with Gitlab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

The Gitlab server is no longer functioning. When typing in

http://myhostname:4332/log_in

the sysetem never comes back and I get a `connection timed out` error

**I have tried to run the following:**

```
  574  sudo strace -tt -T -f -s 1024 -p 4332 -o /tmp/unicorn.txt
  575  sudo strace -tt -T -f -s 1024 -p 8080 -o /tmp/unicorn.txt
```

as part of troubleshooting by following the steps here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/troubleshooting/debug.html

The result is always the same, something like:

```
dgmufasa@mycomputer:~$ sudo strace -tt -T -f -s 1024 -p 4332 -o /tmp/unicorn.txt
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): No such process
```

Below is more information. What can I do to solve the problem?

TIA

**sudo gitlab-ctl show-config**

```
{
  "gitlab": {
    "gitlab-shell": {
      "secret_token": "secret_token",
      "auth_file": "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    },
    "gitlab-rails": {
      "gitlab_default_theme": 4,
      "backup_upload_connection": {
        "provider": "AWS",
        "region": "us-east-2",
        "aws_access_key_id": "aws_access_key",
        "aws_secret_access_key": "aws_secret_key"
      },
      "backup_upload_remote_directory": "myhost-gitlab-bckup-0001",
      "backup_multipart_chunk_size": 104857600,
      "backup_encryption": "AES256",
      "smtp_enable": true,
      "smtp_address": "smtp.gmail.com",
      "smtp_port": 587,
      "smtp_user_name": "myemail@gmail.com",
      "smtp_password": "mypassword",
      "smtp_domain": "smtp.gmail.com",
      "smtp_authentication": "login",
      "smtp_enable_starttls_auto": true,
      "smtp_tls": false,
      "smtp_openssl_verify_mode": "peer",
      "secret_key_base": "secret_key_base",
      "db_key_base": "dev_key_base",
      "otp_key_base": "otp_key_base",
      "openid_connect_signing_key": "signing_key"
      "stuck_ci_jobs_worker_cron": null,
      "gitlab_host": "mycomputer.com",
      "gitlab_email_from": "gitlab@mycomputer.com",
      "gitlab_https": false,
      "gitlab_port": 4332,
      "shared_path": "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared",
      "artifacts_path": "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts",
      "lfs_storage_path": "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/lfs-objects",
      "pages_path": "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/pages",
      "repositories_storages": {
        "default": {
          "path": "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories",
          "gitaly_address": "unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket",
          "failure_count_threshold": 10,
          "failure_wait_time": 30,
          "failure_reset_time": 1800,
          "storage_timeout": 30
        }
      },
      "trusted_proxies": [

      ],
      "db_username": "gitlab",
      "db_host": "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql",
      "db_port": 5432
    },
    "gitlab-workhorse": {
      "secret_token": "secret_token",
      "auth_socket": "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket"
    },
    "logging": {

    },
    "redis": {

    },
    "postgresql": {

    },
    "unicorn": {
      "port": 4333
    },
    "mailroom": {

    },
    "gitlab-pages": {

    },
    "prometheus": {
      "flags": {
        "web.listen-address": "localhost:9090",
        "storage.local.path": "/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data",
        "storage.local.chunk-encoding-version": "2",
        "storage.local.target-heap-size": "106218700",
        "config.file": "/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
      }
    },
    "external-url": "http://mycomputer.com:4332",
    "registry-external-url": null,
    "mattermost-external-url": null,
    "pages-external-url": null,
    "runtime-dir": "/run",
    "bootstrap": {

    },
    "omnibus-gitconfig": {

    },
    "manage-accounts": {

    },
    "manage-storage-directories": {

    },
    "user": {
      "home": "/var/opt/gitlab",
      "git_user_email": "gitlab@mycomputer.com"
    },
    "gitlab-ci": {

    },
    "sidekiq": {

    },
    "mattermost-nginx": {
      "listen_port": null
    },
    "pages-nginx": {
      "listen_port": null
    },
    "registry-nginx": {

    },
    "remote-syslog": {

    },
    "logrotate": {

    },
    "high-availability": {

    },
    "web-server": {

    },
    "gitaly": {
      "storage": [
        {
          "name": "default",
          "path": "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories"
        }
      ]
    },
    "node-exporter": {
      "flags": {
        "web.listen-address": "localhost:9100",
        "collector.textfile.directory": "/var/opt/gitlab/node-exporter/textfile_collector"
      }
    },
    "redis-exporter": {
      "flags": {
        "web.listen-address": "localhost:9121",
        "redis.addr": "unix:///var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket"
      }
    },
    "postgres-exporter": {
      "flags": {
        "web.listen-address": "localhost:9187",
        "extend.query-path": "/var/opt/gitlab/postgres-exporter/queries.yaml"
      }
    },
    "gitlab-monitor": {

    },
    "prometheus-monitoring": {

    },
    "pgbouncer": {

    },
    "sentinel": {

    },
    "mattermost": {
      "email_invite_salt": "invite_salt",
      "file_public_link_salt": "file_salt",
      "sql_at_rest_encrypt_key": "sql_rest_key",
      "sql_data_source": "user=gitlab_mattermost host=/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql port=5432 dbname=mattermost_production",
      "sql_data_source_replicas": [
        "user=gitlab_mattermost host=/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql port=5432 dbname=mattermost_production"
      ]
    },
    "nginx": {
      "custom_gitlab_server_config": "location ^~ /.well-known { root /var/www/letsencrypt; }",
      "proxy_set_headers": {
        "Host": "$http_host_with_default",
        "X-Real-IP": "$remote_addr",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
        "Upgrade": "$http_upgrade",
        "Connection": "$connection_upgrade",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http"
      },
      "real_ip_trusted_addresses": [

      ],
      "listen_port": 4332
    }
  },
  "roles": {
    "application": {

    },
    "redis-sentinel": {

    },
    "redis-master": {

    },
    "redis-slave": {

    },
    "geo-primary": {

    },
    "geo-secondary": {

    }
  },
  "registry": {
    "http_secret": "http_secret",
    "internal_certificate":"internal_certificate",
    "internal_key": "internal_key"
  },
  "repmgr": {

  },
  "repmgrd": {

  },
  "consul": {

  }
}
```

**restarting the system**

```
dgmufasa@mycomputer:~$ sudo gitlab-ctl restart
ok: run: gitaly: (pid 5286) 0s
ok: run: gitlab-monitor: (pid 5296) 1s
ok: run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 5300) 0s
ok: run: logrotate: (pid 5315) 0s
ok: run: nginx: (pid 5329) 1s
ok: run: node-exporter: (pid 5336) 0s
ok: run: postgres-exporter: (pid 5341) 0s
ok: run: postgresql: (pid 5350) 0s
ok: run: prometheus: (pid 5394) 0s
ok: run: redis: (pid 5404) 1s
ok: run: redis-exporter: (pid 5409) 0s
ok: run: sidekiq: (pid 5418) 1s
ok: run: unicorn: (pid 5427) 0s
```

**I executed: dgmufasa@mycomputer:~$  sudo tail -10 /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log**

```
       192.222.22.22 - - [24/Jan/2018:21:55:24 -0600] "GET /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 302 83 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
    192.222.22.22 - - [24/Jan/2018:21:55:28 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7845 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
    192.222.22.22 - - [24/Jan/2018:21:58:50 -0600] "GET /CCLUB-WORK/ccindb-restapi-fieldworkserver HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "http://mycomputer:4332/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
    192.222.22.22 - - [24/Jan/2018:21:58:57 -0600] "GET /CCLUB-WORK/ccindb-restapi-fieldworkserver HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "http://mycomputer:4332/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
    192.222.22.22 - - [24/Jan/2018:21:59:00 -0600] "GET /CCLUB-WORK/ccindb-restapi-fieldworkserver HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "http://mycomputer:4332/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
    192.222.22.22 - - [24/Jan/2018:22:00:51 -0600] "GET /CCLUB-WORK/ccindb-restapi-fieldworkserver HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://mycomputer:4332/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I ran :  **sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure** and everything started working again. I don't know why - so - it would be good to get some kind of hint to know what this command does.

Comment: `reconfigure` updates the DB schema as needed, amongst other things. See this article for more details, and on how to automate this: [Upgrading GitLab with external PostgreSQL](https://noobient.com/post/175240426691/upgrading-gitlab-with-external-postgresql)