# getting 502 Error in gitlab creating project

Tags: gitlab, port, centos7, gitlab-ci

I had Gitlab version 11.8 installed on the Santos server. I installed the old version and installed the new 12 version  based on the Gitlab site instructions. Returns after installation when creating a new project.
i cheacked log by this comman:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl tail
```

there was this error:

```
0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

I checked the links below for similar situations. I didn't find the right answer.
[getting 502 errors with Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436119/getting-502-errors-with-gitlab)
[Can't create project - 502 Error](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/1699)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that after deleting the old version of Gitlab Server, the nginx service had not stopped once. Strangely, after installing the new version of the Gitlab service, it didn't fully communicate with nginx. The problem was solved with a simple reboot.I think the parent of the calling nginx service was the old version of Gitlab service and the new version didn't have full access.